# animate image tags on :target

Tags: html, css

I want to animate the images when they are targetted using `:target`. But the problem is that my image tags are inside div tags so I am unable to target the `img`. How can I do this or if this is even possible? Or if there is any other way to do it?

This is my html

```
<div id="f">
                <img src="images/fan.png">
                <span><h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 6em; padding: 10px;">Fan</h1></span>
            </div>
```

and this is how I am currently trying to do

```
@keyframes  zomeIn{
     from{width: 50px; height: 50px;}
     to{width: 150px; height: 150px;}
 }
:target{

    animation-name: zomeIn;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current code for us to check if it is possible?

Comment: spin up a fiddle and let's see what your working with.

Comment: @ManojKumar Please see my updated question.

Comment: @nykc Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `#f:target img` to select the image inside of a targeted div. Then when you click on an anchor that targets that div, the animation will play on the image.

Here is a **live example:**

```css
@keyframes zomeIn {
    from {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    to {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
}
#f:target img {
    animation-name: zomeIn;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="f">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LDR6AWn.png?1" width="150" height="150">
</div>

<a href="#f">Animate</a>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/v77m1tod/

Comment: I have multiple divs containing imgs like above so how would I  target then? In my case it is not working.

Comment: I would try giving all the divs a class like `imgContainer`. Then for your CSS you could use `.imgContainer:target img`.

Comment: only `.img-container:target` is working, when i put `.img-container:target img` it does not work? any ideas?

Comment: @Adamnick Here's a [jsFiddle that demonstrates what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/v77m1tod/1/). Tell me if you can get it working in your code based off that, and if not, it would be helpful if you reply with a JSFiddle and some details about how you want it to behave. Thanks!